# Finding first date of the range of gap records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set as below - 
In this data set there are start_location missing because the activity_type is No . So basically I want to create a column that has the minimum date of activity_date for every gap ( means the record that do not have start_location) for ex. if 5/07/2015 ,6/07/2015,7/07/2015 have start_location as null then the new column i.e new_activity_date must be first date of gap which is 05/07/2015.

Basically this is to find the first date of the gap period.
Data as below-

```
id  activity_type   activity_date   start_location  end_location
27151   Yes 4/07/2015   18  18
27151   No  5/07/2015       
27151   No  6/07/2015       
27151   Yes 7/07/2015   18  17
27151   Yes 8/07/2015   18  17
27151   Yes 9/07/2015   18  17
27151   Others  19/07/2015  17  17
27151   Others  20/07/2015  17  17
27151   No  21/07/2015      
27151   No  22/07/2015      
27151   No  23/07/2015      
27151   Yes 24/07/2015  17  17
27151   Yes 25/07/2015  17  17
27151   Yes 26/07/2015  17  17
27151   Yes 27/07/2015  17  17
```

My data should look like --

```
id  activity_type activity_date start_location  end_location new_activity_date
27151   Yes 4/07/2015   18  18  4/07/2015
27151   No  5/07/2015           4/07/2015
27151   No  6/07/2015           4/07/2015
27151   Yes 7/07/2015   18  17  7/07/2015
27151   Yes 8/07/2015   18  17  8/07/2015
27151   Yes 9/07/2015   18  17  9/07/2015
27151   Others  19/07/2015  17  17  19/07/2015
27151   Others  20/07/2015  17  17  20/07/2015
27151   No  21/07/2015          20/07/2015
27151   No  22/07/2015          20/07/2015
27151   No  23/07/2015          20/07/2015
27151   Yes 24/07/2015  17  17  24/07/2015
27151   Yes 25/07/2015  17  17  25/07/2015
27151   Yes 26/07/2015  17  17  26/07/2015
27151   Yes 27/07/2015  17  17  27/07/2015
```

Thanks in advance, not sure where I'm misisng the trick.

Comment: go to sqlfiddle.com and we may be able to help you out.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean but I'm looking for a query to solve this issue.

Comment: sqlfiddle is a platform to build your tables and query online because at the moment no one can understand your data

Comment: Trying in sqlfiddle but can't create the table with data, trying though

Comment: try http://rextester.com/ ... should be similar to SSMS

Comment: tried but not sure after executing my query what do I do may be I do not underatnd completely how to use it to my benifit, np thanks.

Comment: well good luck.. you'll need it

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you want.  I'm thinking a function would work best, then you can use it in an insert or update:

```
create function dbo.get_New_Activity_Date(@Activity_Date datetime)
returns datetime
As
Begin 
  declare @result datetime
  set @result=
   (select min(activity_date)
    from myTable
    where activity_date<=@activity_Date
    and activity_date>
        (select max(activity_date)
           from myTable t2 
           where t2.start_location is not null -- if using null else test for blank
           and t2.activity_date <=@activity_date
        )
    )
  return isnull(@result,@activity_date)  
end
```

If you just want a select statement to extract this table as part of ETL job without using function:

```
select 
  id
  ,activity_type
  ,activity_date
  ,start_location
  ,end_location
  ,isnull((select min(t1.activity_date)
    from myTable t1
        where t1.id=myTable.id
        and t1.activity_date<=myTable.activity_Date
        and t1.activity_date>
    (select max(t2.activity_date)
       from myTable t2 
       where t2.id=myTable.id
       and t2.start_location is not null -- if using null else test for blank
       and t2.activity_date <=myTable.activity_date
    )
),activity_date) new_activity_date
from
  myTable
```

My results:

[image]

Comment: Any possibility of making it as a part of select query? Don't want to use function.As this logic is going to be part of an ETL job.

Comment: Yes, I added below function.

Comment: The above one doesn't seem to give me right results as I'm expecting all the records in the group which have start_location as null to have the same date as of the last date when the start_location was not null.

Comment: I think you must have a typo.  Please check my results.  I believe this is what you want.

Comment: I modified the query to -select 
  id
  ,activity_type
  ,activity_date
  ,start_location
  ,end_location
  ,isnull((select min(t1.activity_date)
    from myTable t1
        where t1.activity_date<=myTable.activity_Date
        and t1.activity_date>
    (select max(t2.activity_date)
       from myTable t2 
       where t2.start_location <>'' -- if using null else test for blank
       and t2.activity_date <=myTable.activity_date
    )
),activity_date) new_activity_date
from
  myTable

Comment: I see that your query is doing all the job disregarding the id and that's the issue where as I'm expecting it do all the work for each of the ids so basically grouped by ID.

Comment: The result shown by you is not exactly I want as it is doing all the job without grouping them by id , I need all the dates in the new date column same as the 1st day of the group where start_location was null but grouped  by id and not overall.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean...  I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Ok, I changed it to only look within the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. This looks like a conditional cumulative maximum to me:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when activity_type <> 'No' then activity_date end) over (order by id, date) as new_activity_date
from t;
```

Comment: I think he's looking for the first date of inactivity for the gap, but this gives the last date before the gap.

Comment: The above one doesn't seem to give me right results as I'm expecting all the records in the group which have start_location as null to have the same date as of the last date when the start_location was not null.

Comment: The above one doesn't seem to give me right results as I'm expecting all the records in the group which have start_location as null to have the same date as of the last date when the start_location was not null.I see that the new_activity_date column has got the same date as the activity_date which is not what I want. Plz see the results below-activity_date start_location end_location new_activity_date              2015-07-30 17 17 2015-07-30
2015-07-31 null null  2015-07-31 2015-07-30
2015-08-01 null null  2015-08-01 2015-07-30

Comment: @Mamta . . . The only issue appears to be that "Others" is treated as "Yes" rather than "No".  Fixed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Your output seems to work for only one id but doesn't seem to work over all the ids. for ex it works for - select t.*,
       max(case when activity_type <> 'No' then activity_date end) over (order by id, date) as new_activity_date
from t where t.id=123 but not for select t.*,
       max(case when activity_type <> 'No' then activity_date end) over (order by id, date) as new_activity_date
from t;-- without any where clause. It should look to reset its new actvity date for every id but at the moment when it reaches next id it takes the new activity date of the last record(id)

Comment: @Mamta . . . Perhaps you want to partition by the `id`.  Your sample data only has one id, so it is not clear what to do about it.